# What does MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds in create_event_source_mapping do?

Tags: aws-lambda

The documentation for the boto3 function [create_event_source_mapping](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_event_source_mapping) has 2 defintions for the parameter `MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds`:

1. Discard records older than the specified age. Default -1 (infinite). Minimum 60. Maximum 604800.
2. (Streams) The maximum amount of time to gather records before invoking the function, in seconds.

In my mind, those are different. The first definition says:

If in the given timeframe `MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds` the batch is not filled, discard them.

And the second definition:

If in the given timeframe `MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds` the batch gets send anyway (being a smaller batch).

Which is the correct definition?